# Storing the groupby results in different excel sheet pandas overwrites the excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Hi I'm running a groupby function on pandas and then trying to store its results in an excel with each group name denoting the sheet name, but the excel which generates only contains the last group, i.e. the data is getting overwritten
What is the best way to solve this problem? So that all the groups are stored in different sheets of excel without overwritting

the code i'm using is below

```
grouped_data=df.groupby('required column')
for name, group in grouped_data:
    print(name)
    sname="Warehouse no."+str(name)
    group.to_excel(r'C:\Users\location\Desktop\grouped.xlsx',sheet_name=sname)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `with pd.ExcelWriter` when writing, example:

```
grouped_data=df.groupby('required column')
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\location\Desktop\grouped.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    for name, group in grouped_data:
        print(name)
        sname="Warehouse no."+str(name)
        group.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sname)
```